# Jenkins Pipeline - Parallel steps skip latest Git commits and Ruby's Bundler commands pause unexpectedly

Tags: ruby, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing my first declarative pipeline and I would like to run the Git Checkout and Bundler stage in parallel. When the steps from these stages are executed in parallel, I experience odd behaviors. For example:

1. I want to check out the latest copy of a PR to test. In the parallel step, the check out will fail to get the latest commit and will fetch an older commit as the HEAD. I have verified that the BitBucket server has newer commits than the one checked out.

**Figured this out**: In Bitbucket server, you need to manually access the PR page and refresh the "commit cache". This way the latest commits are served to Jenkins. 
**Source**: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Change-pull-request-refs-after-Commit-instead-of-after-Approval/qaq-p/194702

2. I want to run Ruby's Bundler gem (bundle install & update) in 4 different repositories at the same time. When the parallel step executes, it would unexpectedly pause/hang on `bundle install` in the cr_dbvals repos and not print anything to the console. Have to abort the build at this point.

**Agents OS**: Windows 10 x64

Running these steps sequentially yields the expected results and everything works fine. Not sure what I am missing in my script here:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label "${env.executor_label}"
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Set Build Name') {
      steps {
        script {
          currentBuild.displayName = "#${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - ${env.app_node} - ${env.browser}@${env.NODE_NAME}"
        }
      }
    } // stage('Set Build Name')

    stage('Git Checkout') {
      steps {
        parallel(
          "Git Cucumber-Watir": {
            dir('cucumber-watir') {
              git(url: 'http://git-repo-url/cucumber-watir.git', branch: 'master', changelog: true)
              bat(script: 'git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*')
              bat(script: 'git fetch origin -p')
              bat(script: "git checkout ${env.cucumber_watir_branch}")
            }
          },
          "Git CrModels": {
            dir('cr_models') {
              git(url: 'http://git-repo-url/cr_models.git', branch: 'master', changelog: true)
              bat(script: 'git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*')
              bat(script: 'git fetch origin -p')
              bat(script: "git checkout ${env.cr_models_branch}")
            }
          },
          "Git CaModels": {
            dir('ca_models') {
              git(url: 'http://git-repo-url/ca_models.git', branch: 'master', changelog: true)
              bat(script: 'git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*')
              bat(script: 'git fetch origin -p')
              bat(script: "git checkout ${env.ca_models_branch}")
            }
          },
          "Git CrDbVal": {
            dir('cr_dbvals') {
              git(url: 'http://git-repo-url/cr_dbvals.git', branch: 'master', changelog: true)
              bat(script: 'git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*')
              bat(script: 'git fetch origin -p')
              bat(script: "git checkout ${env.cr_dbvals_branch}")
            }
          }
        ) // parallel
      } // steps
    } // stage('Git Checkout')

    stage('Bundler') {
      steps {
        parallel(
          "Bundle Cucumber-Watir": {
            dir('cucumber-watir') {
              bat(script: "bundle install")
              bat(script: "bundle update")
                  }
          },
          "Bundle CrModels": {
            dir('cr_models') {
              bat(script: "bundle install")
              bat(script: "bundle update")
            }
          },
          "Bundle CaModels": {
            dir('ca_models') {
              bat(script: "bundle install")
              bat(script: "bundle update")
            }
          },
          "Bundle CrDbVal": {
            dir('cr_dbvals') {
              bat(script: "bundle install")
              bat(script: "bundle update")
            }
          }
        ) // parallel
      } // steps
    } // stage('Bundler')

    stage('Execute Test(s)') {
      steps {
        dir(path: 'cucumber-watir') {
          bat 'set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1'
          bat(script: 'cucumber -t %tags% -f json -o cucumber.json -f pretty --expand')
        }
      } // steps
    } // stage('Execute Test(s)')

  } // stages

  post {
      always {
        dir(path: 'cucumber-watir') {
        cucumber 'cucumber.json' // Build Cucumber Report
        }
        deleteDir() // Cleanup
      } // always
  } // post

} // pipeline
```

Comment: I don't really understand why would.you want to run them in parallel. Doing so You will end up bundling an older commit most of the time by the time it will.checkout the new commit.

Comment: Well, for one, it offers faster checkouts across the pipeline. The parallel checkouts are happening in separate directories so they shouldn't affect each other. Right? Am I missing something?

Comment: The checkouts won't affect each other but each checkout will affect the bundle install jobs which depend on the checkout. So bundle install must always happen after a checkout and not in parallel

Comment: Right. The Checkout and Bundle happen in separate parallel stages. First the checkout and then bundler is run. So I ended up using the checkout/GitSCM step to checkout PRs and everything works as expected now. I will be testing the new pipeline script for another week or so before I say that this issue is fully resolved.

Comment: Figured out (1): In Bitbucket server, you need to manually access the PR page and refresh the "commit cache". This way the latest commits are served to Jenkins. Source: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Change-pull-request-refs-after-Commit-instead-of-after-Approval/qaq-p/194702

Comment: For (2) we decided to include the other repos (Ruby gems) into the main repo's `Gemfile` and call `bundle update` from there. This way we only have to run it once.